# throw exception sinch java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: sinch

I was trying to run the sample code from the sdk but I got the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, at the line:

```
sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder()
        .context(this)
        .userId("a")
        .applicationKey("key")
        .applicationSecret("secret")
        .environmentHost("sandbox.sinch.com")
        .build();
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output from when it crashes?

Comment: 05-18 09:19:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 09:19:55.007: E/AndroidRuntime(608): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sinch.android.rtc.Sinch

Comment: Is seems like you have not added the Sinch framework to the project.

Answer (score 3):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means it can't find the class. This is most likely because the Sinch RTC SDK is not properly included in your APK. Make sure that the .jar file is under your `libs/` folder (or, if you are using a custom setup, make sure it's being compiled in to the final package).

Comment: I put it in the lib, but it shows me :05-20 14:14:34.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9455): Process: com.example.sinchdemo, PID: 9455
05-20 14:14:34.241: E/AndroidRuntime(9455): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sinch-android-rtc from loader